# loop and only get status is if true

Tags: ember.js

I want to loop thru this view and be able to only get the status if is only true else if is not true display it on another view on the bottom.

```
    <table class="rounded" >
                Unavailable Requests
               {{#each request in model}}
               <ul>
                    <li> Trip ID: {{request.request_id}}</li>
                    <li> Destination: {{request.destination}}</li>
                    <li >Hotel Name: {{request.hotel_name}} - {{#link-to 'rfp' request.id}}view request{{/link-to}}
                    </li>
                        <li>Status: {{status}}</li>
                    <li>Client: {{request.full_name}} - ({{request.user.email}})</li>    
               </ul>
           {{/each}}
    </table>

App.DashboardRoute = App.AuthRoute.extend({
    model: function(){
        return this.store.find('request');
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance guys.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put an `if` helper in the middle of the template like so:

```
<table class="rounded" >
  Unavailable Requests
  {{#each request in model}}
  <ul>
     <li> Trip ID: {{request.request_id}}</li>
     <li> Destination: {{request.destination}}</li>
     <li >Hotel Name: {{request.hotel_name}} - {{link-to "view request" 'rfp' request}}</li>
     {{#if status}}
        Show the status
     {{else}}
        Show the other view
     {{/if}}
     <li>Client: {{request.full_name}} - ({{request.user.email}})</li>    
   </ul>      
   {{/each}}

</table>
```